# Titanium Mobile editable row moves inner row elements

Tags: ios, titanium, tableview

I have a tableView with multiple TableViewRow objects, always 4.
When the edit button is clicked the row can be reordered, which is working.

But when the edit button is clicked the elements inside of a row seem to be moved with margins from left and right.

The items in a row should not be moved, so I was hoping someone could tell me how I can make sure the labels inside a row element are not being moved around when edited.

I have included some images, hoping to clarify my question:

[image: The rows when NOT edited]
**Rows when not edited**

[image: Rows when being edited]
**Rows when edited**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution was easy, but I didnt know.

The way to achieve this; Add a view to each row and do NOT set the left or right properties.
This way the delete button and move icon are not pushing the inner view away.

Comment: You should click the check mark beside this answer, if it answers your question.

Comment: I know, but I cant for 2 days. "You can accept your own answer in 2 days
(click on this box to dismiss)" So that's why I did not check it yet, sorry but I just can not..

Comment: No problem! It's listed as the solution now!

Answer (score -1):

Its a default behavior. I dont think there's any way defined in Titanium API to override the moving of inner elements. So you cannot change this default behavior.

Comment: I don't understand it's behaviour. The row has an inner view containing everything. No matter what the width of the view even if it is 90px it's always being moved.

Comment: Hasnain, I got it fixed. The solution was to not set the left or right properties on the inner view. I have a different question now though. Is it possible to hide certain elements of each row when they are being edited?